# PhpMyadmin throwing 500 with nginx and Php on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, php, nginx, phpmyadmin

I have tried installing phpmyadmin as mentioned in the link below

https://thelinuxterminal.com/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-ubuntu-22-10/

I followed it step by step but i am getting 500 if i visit the page from my ipAddress.

I checked Php is Installed and I configured nginx as shown below

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    root /usr/share/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        root /usr/share/;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
        root /usr/share/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update you question with the content of `/var/log/nginx/error.log`?